# Not able to mock HTTPResponse in mokito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have to write unit test for this method using mokito, I am facing error while stubbing data

```
{        @Mock
         private HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
         private HttpResponse httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
    {
       when(httpUtil.getRequest(url,"access_token",                                          
      ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
    }

 }
```

method:

```
public List<UGD> getUGD(String ugName, String accessToken) throws IOException,
            InvalidInputException {
        String url = ekauserapiServiceBaseUrl + "uG?gName=" + gName;
        HttpResponse resp = httpUtil.getRequest(url, accessToken,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(resp.getEntity().getContent(),
                    UGD[].class));
        }
        throw new NotFoundException("not found");
    }
```

```
Error : java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal"

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal"

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:262)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:206)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:89)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:435)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.ekahau.client.HttpUtil.getRequest(HttpUtil.java:75)
```

Just want to know what I am doing wrong here ,suggestions are welcome! TIA

Comment: It actually looks like you might have some conflicting versions of jars among your project dependencies.  You'll need to sort that out before you can do anything much.  Also, if you intend `httpUtil` to be a mock, you don't want `= new HttpUtil()` in there.

Comment: You're mocking `httpUtil` with `@Mock`, but `httpRequest` with `mock()`. Why? Use `@Mock` for both (and as @DawoodibnKareem says, don't create an `HttpUtil` instance.) You need to show more of your test: What class is `mock` coming from? Why are you using PowerMock when there's nothing in the code you show which requires it?

Comment: I understand the problem and got resolved it too, but again i am facing new problem : ekauserapiServiceBaseUrl is giving null in unit test. since it is fetching from properties file . and because of this while callling this method getting (url :nulluG?gName=MSG) and since there is protocol appended here , it giving me error org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException , so again my question is how can mock  ekauserapiServiceBaseUrl .

Comment: @Value("${ekauserapi.service.baseurl}")
 private String ekauserapiServiceBaseUrl;